# Error: Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension

Tags: ruby, react-native, cocoapods

getting error when install react native app using `npx react-native init AwesomeProject`
[image]
`
Something went wrong while installing ruby gems
Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

extconf failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in
/Users/yash/Programming/ReactNative/tutorials/AwesomeProject223/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/json-2.6.3
for inspection.
Results logged to
/Users/yash/Programming/ReactNative/tutorials/AwesomeProject223/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/extensions/universal-darwin-22/2.6.0/json-2.6.3/gem_make.out

An error occurred while installing json (2.6.3), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install json -v '2.6.3' --source 'https://rubygems.org/'`
succeeds before bundling.

In Gemfile:
cocoapods was resolved to 1.12.1, which depends on
cocoapods-core was resolved to 1.12.1, which depends on
algoliasearch was resolved to 1.27.5, which depends on json`